# union for array of object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How to extends an property in array of object in typescript?

I have below react code:

```
interface List {
  id: string;
}
interface AppProps {
  list: List[];
}

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ list }) => {
  const [listCustom, setListCustom] = React.useState<List[]>([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setListCustom([
      {
        id: "3",
        newProperty: "new" //issue is here, how to extend List to have newProperty without modifying List?
      }
    ]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
};


export default App;
```

In here

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setListCustom([
      {
        id: "3",
        newProperty: "new" //issue is here, how to extend List to have newProperty without modifying List?
      }
    ]);
  }, []);
```

I have to set new property to List, but I don't want to modify List because it's tied to the AppProps. How can I 'extends' it in line   `const [listCustom, setListCustom] = React.useState<List[]>([]);`?

It doesn't make sense to create a duplicated `List2` like

```
interface List2 {
  id: string;
  newProperty: string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either extend the list interface:

```
interface List2 extends List {
  newProperty: string;
}
```

Or you can use an intersection type:

```
type List2 = List & { newProperty: string }
```

The interface can't be done inline, but the intersection can be:

```
const [listCustom, setListCustom] = React.useState<(List & { newProperty: string })[]>([]);
```